# How to encode phone number when calling in swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, character-encoding

[image]I'm trying to format a phone number into a "01-800-234-0445" for the calling screen.  I can format it into the proper format before trying to execute the call, but when the call is made its in "018002340445" format. I think it has to do with the encoding, this is what I have so far:

phone = "01-800-234-0445" (used for executeCall phone parameter)

```
private func executeCall(phone:String){

let formattedPhone = phone.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!//this formatting doesn't appear to be doing anything

if let url = URL(string: "tel://" + formattedPhone), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I believe that the number that is displayed is formatted by iOS itself, based on the device locale and/or carrier information. If possible, you can supply an e.164 formatted number to give ios a better chance of formatting it for your locality?